# Getting an expression tree from inside a method's body

Tags: c#, .net, orm, expression-trees

#### Context:

I'm making an [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) parser, which would take my LINQ queries, and turn them into specific byte arrays. Think ORM for a custom data storage, euhm, thing. I'll use SQL in my examples for familiarity.

```
class ExpressionParser<T>
{
    public string ParseWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // Takes an expression, follows the expression tree, building an SQL query.
    }
}
```

#### Example:

Take an example class `FooData` with a few dummy properties:

```
class FooData
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

```
var parser = new ExpressionParser<FooData>();
var query = parser.ParseWhere(foo => foo.Active && (foo.Status == 3 || foo.Status == 4));
// Builds "WHERE active AND (status = 3 OR status = 4)"
```

This works great, my parser runs through the expression tree, builds a WHERE statement, and returns it.

#### Problem:

Now I see that, for example, `Active && (Status == 3 || Status == 4)` is a special case that will be used all over the whole project. So naturally I extract it to a computed property:

```
class FooData
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecialThing => Active && (Status == 3 || Status == 4);
}
```

```
var query = parser.ParseWhere(foo => foo.IsSpecialThing);
```

Should the expression be evaluated, the result would be the same. However, this doesn't work any more. Instead of [a full expression tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoDx3.png) that I can make a query from, all I get is [a tree with one `PropertyExpression`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtFkP.png) that tells me nothing.

I tried changing it to a method, adding a `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute, nothing seems to make `Expression` look *inside* my method / property.

#### Question:

Is it possible to make an [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) look deeper - into a property getter / method body? If not - is there an alternative to [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) that would?

If it's not possible at all, what should one do in this case? It would *really* suck to copy-paste long parts of queries tens *(hundreds?)* of times in a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that this:

```
public bool IsSpecialThing => Active && (Status == 3 || Status == 4);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
public bool IsSpecialThing { get { return Active && (Status == 3 || Status == 4); } }
```

Note that they're both *compiled* methods. You can see this because the type is `Func<FooData,bool>`, rather than `Expression<Func<FooData,bool>>`. Short answer: No, you can't inspect it*

If you replace your class definition with this:

```
public class FooData
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<FooData, bool>> IsSpecialThing = (foo) => foo.Active && (foo.Status == 3 || foo.Status == 4); 
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
var parser = new ExpressionParser<FooData>();
var query = parser.ParseWhere(FooData.IsSpecialThing);
```

Note that this raises more difficulties. I'm assuming you'd want to write something like:

```
ParseWhere(f => f.IsSpecialThing() && f.SomethingElse)
```

The problem here is that `IsSpecialThing` is it's own lambda function, with it's own parameters. So it would be equivalent of writing:

```
ParseWhere(f => (ff => IsSpecialThing(ff)) && f.SomethingElse)
```

To combat this, you'd need to write a few helper methods which let you `AND` and `OR` `LambdaExpression`s properly:

```
public class ParameterRewriter<TArg, TReturn> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> _mapping;
    public Expression<Func<TArg, TReturn>> Rewrite(Expression<Func<TArg, TReturn>> expr, Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> mapping)
    {
        _mapping = mapping;
        return (Expression<Func<TArg, TReturn>>)Visit(expr);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
    {
        if (_mapping.ContainsKey(p))
            return _mapping[p];
        return p;
    }
}
```

The above will take a mapping between parameters, and replace them in the given expression tree.

Leveraging it:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        var rewrittenRight = RewriteExpression(left, right);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(left.Body, rewrittenRight.Body), left.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        var rewrittenRight = RewriteExpression(left, right);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, rewrittenRight.Body), left.Parameters);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RewriteExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        var mapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
        for (var i = 0; i < left.Parameters.Count; i++)
            mapping[right.Parameters[i]] = left.Parameters[i];

        var pr = new ParameterRewriter<T, bool>();
        var rewrittenRight = pr.Rewrite(right, mapping);
        return rewrittenRight;
    }
}
```

What the above essentially does is, if you write this:

```
Expression<Func<FooData, bool>> a = f => f.Active;
Expression<Func<FooData, bool>> b = g => g.Status == 5;
Expression<Func<FooData, bool>> c = a.AndAlso(b);
```

Will return you `f => f.Active && f.Status == 5` (note how the parameter `g` was replaced with `f`.

Putting it all together:

```
var parser = new ExpressionParser<FooData>();
var result = parser.ParseWhere(FooData.IsSpecialThing.AndAlso(f => f.Status == 6));
```

---

<sup>*Note it is *technically* possible to parse the generated IL, but you'll be in for a hell of a time.</sup>

Comment: Hi guys! I am also in need for expression to sql and I tried your code just to be more clear what is going on and how this works, but I am stuck as your and OP code is missing "// Takes an expression, follows the expression tree, building an SQL query." What I need to do there? Please see https://pastebin.com/1vYiDu1q Thanks!

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation 'ParseWhere' is irrelevant to the question and answer here, it's just their custom implementation. You can probably remove `ExpressionParser` from your code and just use `Where`. The Q&A deals with extracting `IsSpecialThing => Active && (Status == 3 || Status == 4);` into a re-usable property